# Visual Studio Setup Project Wizard Custom

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, deployment, installation

I want to create a single `.exe` or `.msi` program that creates a custom folder structure (which I know how to code in a vb.net) and then deploy two .exe files into this new folder structure. Thats it! No registery entries or any other type of files are needed.

Do I need to use the VS Setup Project Wizard for the above scenario ? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Decided just to use VS Setup Project Wizard and create custom output folders.